# Alternative to Google Nearby Search

Tags: google-places-api, foursquare, google-places

I am working on a project related to travel, for which I need an API that can provide me popular tourist destinations / things to do (activities) / restaurants in an area or near me.

The [Google Nearby Places](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) seemed exact fit for this scenario, but when I started working with it, I found it bloated with data, which I don't need and cant filter out.

As an example, it lists banks with types such as `Point of Interest` and `Establishment`. There's nothing that differentiates a beach with Banks other than `bank` type, which a bank is also tagged with.

Google has types of places listed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types), but none satisfies what I need.

The type of data I am looking for is places popular with tourists, restaurants and activities that are available at a particular spot. So, for example the data I am looking for is something like:

In a town called Gokarna, we have say A, B, C beaches which are popular among tourists. At A, things that can be done are kayaking and surfing. The famous restaurants available nearby are X, Y, Z. And if possible user reviews.

Can you please suggest me an API that can, if not all, fullfill most of what I am looking for?

I have also gone through foursquare API, and it also seems promising but the issue with it is for working with their places data, we need to register as an enterprise user, which a single developer cannot afford. So a suggestion for cost effective alternative will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Here Maps and their APIs. They have good developer support and only focus on mapping and geographic related things

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.